# JQX Nested Grid Issue - Polymer

Tags: polymer, jqwidget

I am  trying to implement a nested grid in Polymer using JqxGrid (As shown in the demo of Nested Grid, with the same data).
Grid is rendering with parent details, but facing the following issues
1. Only first row is able to expand/collapse
2. Rest of the rows are not collapsing
3. Child grid is fixed in a position
4. Values of child grid are changing on scroll

When tried to launch the grid in a dialog window. The row expand/collapse events are not at all triggering.

How can i resolve this issue?

Try the code in plunker:-
    {http://plnkr.co/edit/f5dHsBIhcIxTQQEggtr6?p=preview}

Try the Pop-up code in plunker:-

```
{http://plnkr.co/edit/JXbEWyCpLNoHflMzXjmG?p=preview}
```

Thanks,
Sanith

Answer (score 0):

You are viewing the wrong example of JqxGrid.

If you are implementing with Polymer goto link: http://www.jqwidgets.com/customelements/grid/grid-row-details.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When tried with custom-elements as well facing the same issue. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Send me the link

Comment: Sorry for a late response.
Here is the plunker URL which uses the JQX custom elements
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q81Fszgz3ZucWA4hYsOe?p=preview

Plunker url when launching the grid in paper-dialog. None of the functionality works.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Hlxeixmw5vtgdfWCnIAA?p=preview

Comment: Please help here